# Get each input attr in iframe

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe on my domain that I would like to get the attribute for each input field. I am using something like the code below but obviously it's not working. Any help with modified code would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$('#iFrame_Id').contents().find(function() { 
   $("#Their_Form :input").each(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
   }
});
```

Comment: Define not working.  Are you getting an error, unexpected behavior, something else?  Also, is the IFrame page on the same domain as the website  you are running.

Comment: Yes same domain. Not returning the attr results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#iFrame_Id').contents().find( "#Their_Form :input" ).each(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `contents` and `find`? You could have done this with one selector.

Comment: @gdoron does jQuery do some magic with iframes automatically? `.contents()` accesses the `document` of the iframe. Otherwise you would just search the iframe element itself which usually has no children.

Comment: So, is my answer wrong? I must go, if it does, I'll delete it when I come back.

Comment: @gdoron well let's make a jsfiddle and find out for sure

Comment: +1, but why `contents()` is needed? how does it work? maybe I'll search the source code later.

Comment: @gdoron if you have just the `iframe` you just have the `iframe` element. To access the `iframe`'s DOM, you need to access `iframe.contentWindow.document` or( `.contentDocument` ) and query that `document`. jQuery's `.contents()` makes a jQuery object ouf of the `iframe`'s `document`.

Comment: `contents: function( elem ) {
  return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) ?
   elem.contentDocument || elem.contentWindow.document :
   jQuery.makeArray( elem.childNodes );`

Comment: If you need it to be faster, skip the `contents` overhead: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHNKj/1/)

Comment: Do you know how can you get the iframe out of the node? http://jsfiddle.net/YHNKj/4/ one way is to search the content of all the iframes look for this one, but it there an easier way?

Comment: @gdoron We could figure it out in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript Is this what you mean though ? http://jsfiddle.net/YHNKj/5/